# Joining multiple Rows and summing them With MySQL (and PHP)

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-tables

I have a table structure similar to this:

```
    id | order1_id | order1_type | order1_amount | order2_id | order2_type | order2_amount
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1        1           3             4                 1         4              5
    2        2           1             1                 1         3              2
    3        1           4             4                 2         2              1
```

I want to get the data like this:

### order_id |  order_type | order_amount

```
1          3            6
1          4            9
2          1            1
2          2            1
```

I want to group by type, and sum the order amounts. How can I do that ?

Thanks,

Comment: you have two types, which one you want to group?

Comment: Both, that's the issue I'm suffering with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to use a union in a subquery to line the columns up, then group and sum on that.

Assuming you're stuck with this less-than-ideal table structure, you may want to create a view that represents the subquery below, then run the group by/sum against that view. I'm guessing such a view might be useful in more places than just this one query.

```
select t.order_id, t.order_type, sum(t.order_amount)
from (select order1_id as order_id, order1_type as order_type, order1_amount as order_amount
      from orders
      union all
      select order2_id as order_id, order2_type as order_type, order2_amount as order_amount
      from orders  
      union all        
      select order3_id as order_id, order3_type as order_type, order3_amount as order_amount
      from orders 
      union all         
      select order4_id as order_id, order4_type as order_type, order4_amount as order_amount
      from orders    
      union all      
      select order5_id as order_id, order5_type as order_type, order5_amount as order_amount
      from orders) t
group by t.order_id, t.order_type
```

Comment: Hmm Thanks! Appreciated! But actually I have rows until order5_id and order5_type, how can I modify the code for that ?

Comment: @Arda: Simply continue to repeat the union all for 3, 4 & 5. I'll extend my answer to show this.

Comment: Thanks, the code works flawlessly! I think I need to study more on using union.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way would be to use a view to untangle the table of questionable design, then group and sum on the view.

```
create view normalized_orders as
select order1_id as order_id, 
    order1_type as order_type,
    order1_amount as order_amount
    from your_table
union all
select order2_id as order_id, 
    order2_type as order_type,
    order2_amount as order_amount
    from your_table
```

Then you can do this:

```
select order_id, order_type, sum(order_amount) 
from normalized_orders
group by order_id, order_type
order by order_id, order_type
```

Comment: That's exactly what I said in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654089/joining-multiple-rows-and-summing-them-with-mysql-and-php/4654160#4654160) Mike.

Comment: Thank you, too for the answer :)